# AngularJS UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

is it possible to Bind multiple field value into single cell of the grid. Please see the sample image below.

[Example like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUb5K.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use cellTemplate, into this you can import html file or write in js like i did.
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myData = [{
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton"
    }];
    
    var template = '';
    template += '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">';
    template += ' {{row.entity.firstName}} ';
    template += ' {{row.entity.lastName}}';
    template += ' </div>';
    
    var columnDefs = [
        {field: 'firstName', displayName: 'Name', cellTemplate: template},
        {field: 'company', displayName: 'Company'}
    ];
    
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: columnDefs
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/v3.0.6/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/v3.0.6/ui-grid.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```